# Keep file with terms in application

Tags: android

I have application where I need to add file with terms. This is a lot of text so I don't want to add this text to strings.xml. Any idea how can add file with terms? Now I have this terms in docx.

Comment: what do you mean by *file with terms* ?

Comment: Just create a additional file called `terms.xml` next to your `strings.xml`. And put your text as a string into it. You can have more than one xml-file with strings in a project.

Comment: docx? Seriously? Can't you just cut and paste the text from docx into a plain.txt. Dealing with docx programmatically is going to be complicated. It's basically a zip folder that includes lots of poorly documented xml. Just take a look at it for yourself. Rename its file extension to .zip and unzip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to put your web resources into the assets folder then call webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");

filename.html will have your terms and condition text with html tag